# How to install the Microsoft.NET.Sdk on Windows Server 2019 Core?

Tags: msbuild, sdk, console, server-core, winget

I want to build my project in a docker desktop windows container.
The OS is Windows Server 2019 Core (no interface, just a console).

If I want to build my solution with MSBuild like that:

> msbuild MySolution.sln

I get this error message:

> MyProject.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

Which means for me that I need to install Microsoft.NET.Sdk, for which I need to install the 'App Installer' (to get the 'winget' commands).
And for that I need the Microsoft Store which is not supported in Windows Server 2019 Core.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Edit:

- projects in the solution are mixed of .NET Framework and .NET Core/.NET
- msbuild is installed via 'Build Tools for Visual Studio' installation
- How can I install the framework with command line?

Comment: Are the projects in the solution .NET Framework or .NET Core/.NET or a mix of both? How is MSBuild installed? Is MSBuild installed via a '[Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022)' installation? SDK projects are usually  .NET Core/.NET. Has [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) been installed?

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft documentation "[Install .NET on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70)" there are sections for installations methods that don't use `winget`:

- "[Install with Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-with-windows-installer)"
- "[Install with PowerShell automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-with-powershell-automation)"